# Xcode Organizer device status "TakingInstallLock" and hangs, only cure is full iOS restore

Tags: xcode, timezone, uilocalnotification, freeze, xcode-organizer

I'm building apps that use UILocalNotifications for alerts. To test scheduling logic, I frequently have to change the system time by minute or hour increments, or change the time zone, etc.

The problem is that after a few sessions of doing this, the Organizer device tab shows a status called "TakingInstallLock" with an indefinite hang in the progress indicator.

1) Is this caused by changing the system time?
2) If not, then what?
3) Or if it is, how else can I test UILocalNotifications that are spaced anywhere from minutes to weeks apart?

Answer (score 8):

A hanging on "TakingInstallLock" can be caused by a long installation process running on the iPhone. For example while you download and install a large game on the device, XCode will show this message if you try to run a project at the same time.

Comment: That is good to know. Although, I doubt that this is the cause of the problem for me as there were no downloads during this time. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem a moments ago, (TakingInstallLock message for undefined time)

What I did was restart xCode and the Device, but I still had the message. What made the difference was to force quit xCode with the Activiy Monitor, and delete the application from the phone. Then I opened Xcode and could re-run my project with no problems.

Hope this help someone.

-

As a note to the OP , I also had this problem when I was modifying my phone date to test future events. It may have something to do.

Comment: I was experiencing very long (30 seconds or more) TakingInstallLock phases yesterday after never seeing it before. I was not actually hanging. This solution sounded a bit like voodoo - how could a force quit address this? But it worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: I had never seen this issue up until today when I opened up xcode for the first time in a couple of weeks. This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I had this problem and could not force quit, but unplugging the device from USB stopped the debugging session. After that, deleting the app from the device fixed things... somehow. With Apple dev tools it seems like every 10 minutes I am here at SO trying to get past the next roadblock.

Answer (score 7):

It has to do with modifying the date. If you install your app at say 10:20PM and then set your date back or in the future and try to run the app again, you will get this issue.

Comment: How did you discover this? Is it reproducible every time?

Comment: I discovered this as it was happening during test of my app, where I was setting altering the date/time to run some tests. Yes, it happens everytime.  Try it. Run your app through your device instead of the simulator. Then close the app change the date on your iPad to something in the past (12 days and the hour to something other than your current time so 3:45AM). Then run the app again through xcode on your iPad. Then let some time go by as your app is running. Then close the app. Change the time back to 3:45AM and run again. YOu should see it.

Comment: Set the date of my device to today (no restart of Xcode or device) and the error disappeared. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I took over a colleague's iPad on which he had previously installed the same app. Terminating Xcode and uninstalling the app from the device before trying again fixed this problem.

After this I got a "application signed with wrong entitlements" problem which I fixed by installing the appropriate provisioning profile.

I later discovered that the iPad clock was set to January 1 1970, so that may be a contributing factor, but I was nonetheless able to debug my app before adjusting the clock.